# Facebook Ads api length of get_results() list

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

While checking `len(async_jon.get_results())` it is giving 25 and when I print it also it is showing 25 records on the console but when I loop through it below, it is showing more records. What is happening here and how I can get the same length when I ran `len(async_jon.get_results())`?

```
data_list = []
for item in async_job.get_result():
                    data = item.export_data()
                    data_list.append(data)
```

`get_resuls()` length from faceboob adinsights api

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Facebook Graph API returns paginated results.
Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/results/

So, here in our case, when we're checking result of `async_jon.get_results()` it is giving as 25 because by default limit is applied as 25.

However at the end of code execution, we're getting more count in `data_list` list because it is storing all paginated results.